# Issue with tabs duplication in Apache Superset

Tags: business-intelligence, apache-superset

I am a beginner at Superset. While working I came across an issue i.e. when I am creating a dashboard using 2 or more tabs components then the last chart that is added in the chats are duplicated in the rest of the tabs.

Answer (score 5):

Your charts are not really duplicated, they are out of the tab, so it is showing at the "main" page of your dashboard.

In order to display a chart in a specific tab, you have to drag and drop the object inside the tab. You should see a blue line when moving it, right below the tab name, indicating you are moving to the correct spot, just like this:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuMdA.png)

This will organize your charts the way you expect.